# How to return the error in kivy's UrlRequest

Tags: python, kivy

I'm currently working on a project to create a program which searches for an airport's METAR report. I have used Kivy's UrlRequest as follows:

```
def search_location(self):
    search_template = "https://avwx.rest/api/metar/{}?options=summary&format=json&onfail=cache"
    search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
    print(2)
    request = UrlRequest(url=search_url, on_success=self.found_location, on_error=print("jdf"), on_failure=print("gsjgv"))
```

I get this returned in the interpreter:

2

jdf

gsjgv

which means that the everything upto the request is ok but there is an error with the request.

The API link works, for example you can use EGCC instead of the {}, which, on the website should rerun JSON data for Manchester Airport.

Is there any way which the UrlRequest can tell me what the error is? The only thing I found in the docs was the on_error parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change print("jdf") and print("gsjgv")  to  print

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, I have got an authorisation error: "'validation_error': 'You are missing the "Authorization" header or "token" parameter.'". How come I need authoriasation here whereas if I were to use the link directly on my browser, I don't? And how would one fix this?

Comment: That error is not from kivy but your API needs authentication. You are probably already authenticated by what you are using some token.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks again, i'll investigate.

Comment: @eyllanesc How would you add a Url header to the link? Or a parameter?

Comment: see the docs: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html